# Token distribution to many users in substrate

Tags: pallet

I'm planning to write a pallet to distribute token to many users in substrate blockchain (Ex: 500k-1m users). Should I do a for loop in a user list and transfer token to them? Do you have any example?

Comment: Is it a one-time job? Or a call that you could call it multiple times?

Comment: I like one-time job than call it multiple times. Do you know the advantage/disadvantage of each way. Just wonder can we distribute token to 500k-1m users with one-time job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are easy to implement. But if it is an extrinsic call, you might need to pay more attention to the bandwidth/weight costs.

---

One-time job in migration way.

Find your `Executive` type in the runtime `lib.rs` and add a `TokenDistribution`:

```rust
pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
+   TokenDistribution,
>;
```

Define the struct `TokenDistribution` and implement `OnRuntimeUpgrade` for it:

```rust
use frame_support::traits::OnRuntimeUpgrade;

pub struct TokenDistribution;
impl OnRuntimeUpgrade for TokenDistribution {
    fn on_runtime_upgrade() -> Weight {
        let fund_account = x;
        let distribute_amount = y;

        load_user_list().into_iter().for_each(|user: AccountId| {
            // `Balances` is the pallet name of your `pallet-balances` 
            // instance which defines in the runtime `lib.rs`           
            Balances::transfer(
                Origin::signed(fund_account),
                user.into(),
                distribute_amount
            );
        });
        
        // Or you could calculate a more precise weight here
        RuntimeBlockWeights::get().max_block
    }
}
```

---

In the next runtime upgrade, the distribution will be applied.

I believe this is the cleanest way to do it.

And remember to remove these codes before the next-next runtime upgrade.

Comment: Can we do 500k-1m transactions in 1 extrinsic call. Is there any limit by BlockWeight or anything else?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about that. But you could split it into multiple calls. It looks like this `Vec<Scheduler::schedule(Utility::batch(Vec<transfer>))>`. Make sure that your chain has `pallet-scheduler` and `pallet-utility`,

Comment: hi @AurevoirXavier i want to call pallet_session set_keys. can you please guide me