# What is simplest way to get native holders distribution?

Tags: storage, democracy, indexing

I want to setup some democracy on one chain. Democracy is voting with tokens.
So it is important to know if tokens distributed well enough.

I looked into some tools and indexers, none provided such information.

Simplest solution I thought of to take storage snapshot and go over `balances account` prefix.

I tried polkadotjs, but it seems "empty"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you already started your chain? If not, you could have the accounts and balances in the genesis config:

```rust
#[pallet::genesis_config]
pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> {
    pub balances: Vec<(T::AccountId, T::Balance)>,
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/fbddfbd76c60c6fda0024e8a44e82ad776033e4b/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L567-L570

OR

You could use [`transfer()`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/fbddfbd76c60c6fda0024e8a44e82ad776033e4b/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L262-L286) (if you have a fund account) or [`setBalance()`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L302-L356).

Keep in mind [`setBalance()`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L302-L356) [requires root origin](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/fbddfbd76c60c6fda0024e8a44e82ad776033e4b/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L321). Do you have a sudo key?

`setBalance()` will alter `FreeBalance` and `ReservedBalance` in storage for an account and it will also alter the total issuance so make sure this is what you intend. It will overwrite the balance.

Write a script using polkadotJS api to iterate over accounts and call the `balances -> setBalance()` extrinsic. Coupling this with a `batch_all` call might make things easier depending on the number of accounts you need to update.

For example:

```js
await api.tx.sudo.sudo(api.tx.balances.setBalance(...))
```

Note: I would not modify state directly like you mentioned, it could lead to undesired consequences.

The simplest and cleanest way may be to do a storage migration. Check this post out:

- [Token distribution to many users in substrate](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/token-distribution-to-many-users-in-substrate)

Answer (score 0):

I got help and got script via polkadotjs, not direct storage usage. But after digging what accounts own what, found https://.subscan.io/account does it. Need to clock more in subscan.